# if else statement in rails controller not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to put validation to my `form_tag` fields: If the user does not select the start date or end date then should be redirected to the same page. I am doing this using 'if else' statement in my controller. But if else statement is not working.

Below is my controller action :

```
def dateFilter  
  cat_id = params[:Category]
  if cat_id == ''
    @expensesFiltered = current_user.expenses.where(:created_at => (params[:start_date].to_date .. params[:end_date].to_date))
  elsif params[:start_date] == ''
    redirect_to '/expenses/dateForm'
  elsif params[:end_date] == ''
    redirect_to '/expenses/dateForm'
  else
    @expensesFiltered = current_user.expenses.where(:created_at => (params[:start_date].to_date .. params[:end_date].to_date)). where("category_id = ?", cat_id[:id])
  end
  @total = @expensesFiltered.sum("amount")
end
```

Here is my view `dateForm.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'expenses', :action => 'dateFilter'}, :class =>"datepicker") do %>
<%= collection_select Category, :id, Category.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Please select category..." %>
<%= label_tag("Start Date") %> <br />
<%= text_field_tag(:start_date) %>
<%= label_tag("End Date") %> <br />
<%= text_field_tag(:end_date) %>
<%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

It does not get redirected and gives error. Please suggest.

If the end_date is not selected it gives me no method error instead of redirecting as given in the `if` condition. Server log is as below:

```
Started POST "/expenses/dateFilter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-21 17:10:15 +0530
Processing by ExpensesController#dateFilter as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"b9eGV7op60letvlaV/62KpAh56KSbD4bd6jhiLeulOk=", "Category"=>{"id"=>"8"}, "start_date"=>"", "end_date"=>"", "commit"=>"Submit"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/expenses/dateForm
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `sum' for nil:NilClass):
```

app/controllers/expenses_controller.rb:50:in `dateFilter'

If the category is not selected, then instead of executing the query in the " if cat_id = '' " it executes the query in the else part and gives no records.
Below is the server log :

```
Started POST "/expenses/dateFilter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-21 16:54:36 +0530
Processing by ExpensesController#dateFilter as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"b9eGV7op60letvlaV/62KpAh56KSbD4bd6jhiLeulOk=", "Category"=>{"id"=>""}, "start_date"=>"2015-01-03", "end_date"=>"2015-01-05", "commit"=>"Submit"}
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 (0.4ms)  SELECT SUM("expenses"."amount") AS sum_id FROM "expenses" WHERE "expenses"."user_id" = ? AND ("expenses"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-01-03' AND '2015-01-05') AND (category_id = '')  [["user_id", 1]]
Expense Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "expenses".* FROM "expenses" WHERE "expenses"."user_id" = ? AND ("expenses"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-01-03' AND '2015-01-05') AND (category_id = '') ORDER BY created_at DESC  [["user_id", 1]]
Rendered collection (0.0ms)
Rendered expenses/dateFilter.html.erb within layouts/application (36.2ms)
Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.5ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1120ms (Views: 945.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: also paste the server console output, I mean not just the error

Comment: as a side note, `cat_id = params[:Category]`  probably always returns nil, i think it's either `params[:category_id]` or `params[:category]`

Comment: add error in question

Comment: @Nicholas Smith I have edited and posted the console output and the error.

Comment: @Ansar I have edited and posted the console output and the error.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I found my mistake...in my ' if cat_id == '' ' , I gave " if cat_id[:id] = '' " and it worked fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `redirect_to` doesn't exit the `dateFilter` method, so

```
  @total = @expensesFiltered.sum("amount")
```

will get executed regardless of the conditionals. If that's the case, you should be able to solve this by appending `return` statements to both `elseif` blocks

```
  # [...]
  elsif params[:start_date] == ''
    redirect_to '/expenses/dateForm'
    return
  elsif params[:end_date] == ''
    redirect_to '/expenses/dateForm'
    return
  else
  # [...]
```

or *alternatively* by moving the calculation of `@total` into the `else` block.

```
  # [...]
  else
    @expensesFiltered = current_user.expenses.where(:created_at => (params[:start_date].to_date .. params[:end_date].to_date)). where("category_id = ?", cat_id[:id])
    @total = @expensesFiltered.sum("amount")
  end
  # [...]
```

This should at least get rid of the `NoMethodError (undefined method`sum' for nil:NilClass)` error. Whether it'll also make the redirections work, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I'd suggest using [scopes](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/) for this. They have built in support for testing if a parameter is present or not, and follow the "skinny controllers, fat models" philosophy. Something like this:

Controller

```
@expensesFiltered = current_user.expenses.date_filter(params[:start_date], params[:end_date]).category_filter(params[:category])
```

Model

```
scope :date_filter, -> (start_date, end_date) { where (:created_at =>  (start_date.to_date .. end_date.to_date)) if start_date.present? and end_date.present? } 

scope :category_filter, -> (category) { where ("category_id = ?", category) if category.present? }
```

Comment: I tried it but got a syntax error. Probably because it has to be like category_id = params [:Category][:id] and I am not sure how to give it in the scope. Please suggest.

Comment: Parameters are strings.. it doesn't make sense to call [:id] on a parameter. Syntax errors are easy to fix, just read what the errors tell you

Comment: Check Mohameds comment, the name of your parameter is probably wrong

Comment: I found my mistake...in my ' if cat_id == '' ' , I gave " if cat_id[:id] = '' " and it worked fine...Thanks a lot for the suggestions...it helped me find out the error.